# Which Symfony version (3.0 or 4.0) is closer to 3.4?

Tags: symfony

I need to learn Symfony 3.4 for a new job but I am finding it very difficult to find well written introduction tutorials.  I already tried to learn through the official Symfony documentation but I still have a lot of questions.  Since it's much easier to find courses and demo-applications for versions 3.0 and 4.0, I want to know which one is closer to 3.4 so that I can use that information to help learn 3.4.

**UPDATE**

With all the different answers I decided to learn little of both. What I noticed is both versions have their own differences to 3.4 one. While  the version 3 has outdated services like this:[image][Link here](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony3/services-useful-objects)

Version 4 has differences in it's structure [image: architecture of version 4]architecture of version 4

[image: architecture of version 3]architecture of version 3

In conclusion, since my problem was understanding the official documentation due to vague experience with php frameworks, MVC model, and Object Oriented programming I decided to learn first the version 4 because it has a bunch of tutorials for beginners and also the [symfony-demo](https://github.com/symfony/demo).

OBS: This [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5ZedKnWX9E)  helped me a lot.

Comment: Go with 4.1 - https://symfony.com/roadmap. 4.0 is not supported anymore

Comment: Consider changing accepted answer. You should accept answer provided by Trix, as the answer is 3.0 not 4.0

Comment: And this is exactly why these sorts of vague opinion based questions are ill-suited for sof.  The only reasonable answer is: it depends.

Comment: @cerad is right,, its probably going to boil down to people's opinion but I've responded by editing my answer.

Comment: That said, @bijibuji, would love to hear your comment on why you think its wrong, you can comment on my answer.

Comment: "You are browsing the Symfony 4 documentation, which changes significantly from Symfony 3.x. If your app doesn't use Symfony 4 yet, browse the Symfony 3.4 documentation."

Comment: @Trix the documentation differences between 3.4 and 4.0 are mostly because they reference different folder structure but the differences between e.g 3.0 and 4.1 are many, hence why they use this blanket statement 3.x and 4.x. But at OP found out in his edit, 3.4 syntax is compatible with 4.0 RE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53356773/which-symfony-version-3-0-or-4-0-is-closer-to-3-4/53356922?noredirect=1#comment93614319_53356922

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, go with Symfony 4.0

A lot of times with Symfony, when we reach the brink of a new major version like 4.0 what you'll find more often than not is that the previous last minor version, in this 3.4 is mostly compatible with it, just that deprecated features are removed.

In other words, the biggest change between 3.4 and 4.0 is that any features marked as deprecated in 3.4 won't work in 4.0.

Whereas the major difference between 3.0 and 3.4 is all the new goodies that convinced the team to leap from 3.4 to 4.0

There are a few minor stuff but this is the biggest difference in my opinion, so go with 4.0 which also has the added benefit of saving you another leap when 5.0 comes out end of next year.

All the best!

### EDIT

Allow me to respond to the other answer that has been surprisingly more popular.

If the question is "Which Symfony version (3.0 or 4.0) is closer to 3.4?" I am genuinely surprised that anyone would say 3.0, genuinely.

Symfony 4 is Symfony 3.4 without support for any deprecated features. - that is the main point here.

Symfony 3.0 is Symfony 2.8 without support for any deprecated features.

Don't take my word for it, check out the official blog on the parity https://symfony.com/blog/category/living-on-the-edge

[image]

Notice how 3.4 and 4.0 are grouped, as well as 2.8 and 3.0.

The closest to 3.4 is 4.0, why? You can safely downgrade from 4.0 to 3.4 without issues (unless with 3rd party bundles), you can also safely upgrade from 3.0 to 3.4 but mostly with deprecation notices everywhere not to mention your code lacks the features introduced in 3.1, 3.2 and 3.3. I'm baffled why some would think the closest to 3.4 is 4 minor versions back. But they gave reasons so I'll briefly counter them.

1. Semantic Versioning really is just numbers, what's important are
   which feature set is closest to 3.4, 4.0 or 3.0?
2. Symfony flex is not Symfony. In fact it is completely separate and
   my production app is using the latest Symfony 4 version without
   flex.
3. Perhaps the now chosen answer was not aware of this, but directory structure is totally optional, my aforementioned production app uses Symfony 3.4 directory structure in my Symfony 4.1.x backend. Just make sure composer.json is aware of your structure.

   "autoload": {
       "psr-4": {
           "AppBundle\": "src/AppBundle/"
       },
       "classmap": [
           "app/AppKernel.php",
           "app/AppCache.php"
       ]
   },
4. Symfony 4 **advises** against using bundles to organize your code, it's not set in stone, again just related to above, let composer know that your code is in src/AppBundle.

Actually, to conclude, most of the reasons stated to choose 3.0 are cosmetic, however, should you want to know which features are in 3.0 that are not in 3.4 take a look at the link I put, here it is again.
https://symfony.com/blog/category/living-on-the-edge

In the end, it's people's opinion, and I'm happy to let the popular one carry the day even if it aint my own.

Good luck!

Comment: The question is not about FEATUREs, it's all about SYNTAX & GRAMMER

Comment: Not even sure what that means, because isn't it the features that determine how you syntactically or grammatically call a function/service? Either way, feel free to edit your answer and explain that part if you want.

Comment: All cars generally have gearbox and that's a FEATURE. Some have manual and the rest have automatic gearboxes and that's Syntax. You are going to buy a new manual-gearbox car and need to learn how to drive. Do you rent an old manual-gearbox car or a new automatic-gearbox one?

Comment: Ok, if you insist, feel free to edit your answer and add that analogy if you want. Cheers.

Comment: Well, since we can't have a clear questions I sent a email to symfony support and they Said: "When using the recommended Symfony practices (and the recommended modern directory structure) 3.4 is very similar to 4.0."

Comment: @GabrielBorgesit was smart of you to contact Symfony support. So I guess you have a choice to make... you can decide to compare the framework to a gearbox... or you can follow official advice... either way, best SO practice is to accept one answer and move on.

Comment: I have used 2.8, 3.0, 3.4, 4.0 and 4.1 in many projects and according to my experience, 3.4 is much close to 3.0 not 4.0

Comment: @bijibuji Oddly, I've also done the same since 1.x Perhaps it just depends on what angle you look at it from - directory structure or framework features. Anyway, OP contacted Symfony support and I'm glad they concurred with my opinion. I'm still surprised that so many think otherwise but my guess is that at a lower level (e.g structure) 3.0 seems similar but at a deeper level 4.0 can do what 3.4 can.

Comment: I think, the question is not what that version can do. the question is similarity to help learning. I dont think 3.4 is similar to 4. I think one should go with 3.0 if he need to learn how to use 3.4

Answer (score 4):

I don't admire or event approve the accepted answer as it is totally wrong!

According to the question by OP,

> I need to learn Symfony 3.4 for a new job. Since it's much easier to find courses and demo-applications for versions 3.0 and 4.0, I want to know which one is closer to 3.4?

Obviously 3.0 is the answer.

As the documentation [clearly states](https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html), Symfony uses [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) strategy:

> - A new Symfony patch version (e.g. 2.8.15, 4.1.7) comes out roughly every month. It only contains bug fixes, so you can safely upgrade your apps;
> - A new Symfony minor version (e.g. 2.8, 3.2, 4.1) comes out every six months: one in May and one in November. It contains bug fixes and new features, but it doesn't include any breaking change, so you can safely upgrade your apps;
> - A new Symfony major version (e.g. 3.0, 4.0) comes out every two years. It can contain breaking changes, so you may need to do some changes in your apps before upgrading.

Also please note that:

> Starting from the **Symfony 3.x** branch, the number of minor versions is limited to five per branch (X.0, X.1, X.2, X.3 and X.4). The last minor version of a branch (e.g. 3.4, 4.4, 5.4) is considered a **long-term support (LTS)** version and the other ones are considered **standard** versions.

which means that only major releases (such as 2.0, 3.0, 4.0) are allowed to break backward compatibility. Minor releases (such as 3.0, 3.1, 3.4) may introduce new features, but must do so without breaking the existing API of that release branch (3.x in the previous example)

So, 3.4 is the LTS and gets support for 3 years. You may also check their [Backward Compatibility Promise](https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/bc.html) for more information.

## Symfony 3.x vs 4.x

Symfony 3.4 & 4.0 have exact same features but different implementations.

According to [Symfony 4 Introduction page](https://symfony.com/4), It was a major release with bunch of whole changes to the framework:

```
|            Feature             | 3.0 | 3.4 | 4.0 |
|--------------------------------|-----|-----|-----|
| Flex                           | No  | No  | Yes |
| Recipes                        | No  | No  | Yes |
| Micro-Kernel Start             | No  | No  | Yes |
| Using Bundles To Organize Code | Yes | Yes | No  |
| Directory Structure            | Old | Old | New |
| composer.json Structure        | Old | Old | New |
| Routing Definition             | Old | Old | New |
| Configuration                  | Old | Old | New |
| Routing Annotations            | Old | Old | New |
```

So if you need to learn 3.4 and you have a choice between 3.0 and 4.0, stick with 3.0 and forget about 4.0

Comment: Good answer @trix but I've responded to it below.